# Convert SQL dump to JSON?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, json, mediawiki

I have a SQL dump from MediaWiki and I want to export it to JSON - I've tried different ways but I can't seem to find any solution. The sql-file looks like this:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `geo_tags`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
CREATE TABLE `geo_tags` (
  `gt_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `gt_page_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `gt_globe` varbinary(32) NOT NULL,
  `gt_primary` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `gt_lat` decimal(11,8) DEFAULT NULL,
  `gt_lon` decimal(11,8) DEFAULT NULL,
  `gt_dim` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `gt_type` varbinary(32) DEFAULT NULL,
  `gt_name` varbinary(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `gt_country` binary(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `gt_region` varbinary(3) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`gt_id`),
  KEY `gt_page_primary` (`gt_page_id`,`gt_primary`),
  KEY `gt_page_id_id` (`gt_page_id`,`gt_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4507036 DEFAULT CHARSET=binary ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC;
```

Followed by a few lines with **INSERT INTO**.

```
INSERT INTO `geo_tags` VALUES (3,487781,'earth',1,59.00000000,10.00000000,1000,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL)
```

Whenever I try to import the sql file into an SQL nothing happens. Is there any easy solution to convert my data to JSON?

Comment: This one is very easy to use, works well with your example: http://www.csvjson.com/sql2json

Comment: @Galz You are totally right! But I have one problem tho, it seems like it only takes the first values from the INSERT INTO 'geo_tags' VALUES, and skips the rest :/ Any idea?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Posting as an answer as I can't post the image in the comments. http://www.csvjson.com/sql2json seems to work fine with several lines. Maybe it has some limit?

How many records are you trying to insert?

[image]

**UPDATE**
Rockstar Martin Drapeau, the guy behind csvjson.com, just implemented my [feature request](https://github.com/martindrapeau/csvjson-app/issues/11), so now mysqldump INSERT syntax will work on his website. Try it [here](http://www.csvjson.com/sql2json/688575184b1e31c39c1fd8786f0509ec).

Comment: I am trying to insert around 400 records, but the difference from my sql file to yours is that mine are lined up with and separated with a comma.

Like this: 
INSERT INTO 'geo_tags' VALUES (....), (.....), (......) etc.

Comment: Yeah, seems like it doesn't support that. Try googling some other tools - that's just the first I found. Also, if this is a one-time operation, you can always convert your query to multiple inserts... OR you can go on github and enhance his/her code to support your use case!

Comment: Thank you so much for you help so far :) I'll either do the manual job by dividing them into single lines - or look for another alternative :)

Comment: I submitted this as an issue for the nice guy who developed the site: https://github.com/martindrapeau/csvjson-app/issues/11

Comment: BTW - it would probably not be a bad idea to convert mysqldump to CSV, and the csv to JSON... There may be more tools that do each one of those than directly from dump to syntax to JSON

Comment: @IvanLeHjelmeland - check out the update. You should be able to use this syntax now!

Comment: Yes, I also sent him an email last night, awesome!! Thank you again so much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You can use command line tool instead using web services:

```bash
# or install via pip
$ pipx install sqldump2json

# each insert statement converts to json object (JSONL)
$ sqldump2json -i testdata/dump.sql
{"table_name": "actor", "values": [1, "PENELOPE", "GUINESS", "2006-02-15 04:34:33"]}
{"table_name": "actor", "values": [2, "NICK", "WAHLBERG", "2006-02-15 04:34:33"]}
{"table_name": "actor", "values": [3, "ED", "CHASE", "2006-02-15 04:34:33"]}
...

# use jq to process json lines
$ sqldump2json -i testdata/dump.sql | jq -r 'select(.table_name == "actor").values | @tsv'
1       PENELOPE        GUINESS 2006-02-15 04:34:33
2       NICK    WAHLBERG        2006-02-15 04:34:33
3       ED      CHASE   2006-02-15 04:34:33
```