# How to convert a local sql file to json with nodejs

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, json, node.js

I want to convert a local sql file ( backup.mysql, around 50mb ) to json format in node, I googled around on some plugins but no luck, most of them need a sql server to convert the data. Does any reader or plugin could convert a sql file to json? thanks!

This is what my sql file look like:

```
INSERT INTO `field_data_body` VALUES ('node','post','0','7112','1942','und','0','<p style="text-align: ce...  <-- 14269 lines like this.
```

I want to convert sql to json in nodejs:

```
    _fs.readFile( _path.in[_i], _encode, ( _err, _result ) => {
        if( _err )
        c.log( '$fs.readFile(), ' + _err );
        else {
            _result = _schema + '=' + JSON.stringify( _result, null, 4 ); //<-- what should i do with _result?
            _fs.writeFile( _path.out[_i], _result, _err => {
                if( _err )
                c.log( '$fs.writeFile(), ' + _err );
                else
                c.log( 'convert "' + _path.in[_i] + '" to "' + _path.out[_i] + '"' );
            });
        }
    });.
```

**UPDATE**

I know there a tool ( http://www.csvjson.com/sql2json ) could do such a job, but my sql data is too large to process.

**UPDATE 2**

Thank to Yohanes Gultom, the following code will did the trick.

```
//dependence libraries
//fs underscore underscore.string
const
c = console,
_fs = require( 'fs' ),
_path = {
    in: [
        'in.mysql',
    ],
    out: [
        'out2.json',
    ],
},
_encode = 'utf-8';

for( let _i in _path.in ) {
    if( _path.out[_i] ) {
        _fs.readFile( _path.in[_i], _encode, ( _err, _result ) => {
            if( _err )
            c.log( '$fs.readFile(), ' + _err );
            else {
                _result = JSON.stringify( $convert( _result ) );
                _fs.writeFile( _path.out[_i], _result, _err => {
                    if( _err )
                    c.log( '$fs.writeFile(), ' + _err );
                    else
                    c.log( 'convert "' + _path.in[_i] + '" to "' + _path.out[_i] + '"' );
                });
            }
        });
    }
}

//
const
_ = require( 'underscore' ),
s = require( 'underscore.string' );
function $convert(a){if(0==a.length)throw errorEmpty;a=a.replace(/(?:\/\*(?:[\s\S]*?)\*\/)|(?:([\s;])+\/\/(?:.*)$)/gm,"$1").replace(/^--.*[\r\n]/gm,"").replace(/^\s*[\r\n]/gm,"").replace(/;\s*[\r\n]/gm,";;").replace(/[\r\n]/gm," ").replace(/;;\s?/gm,";\n");var b=_.lines(a);if(0==b.length)throw errorEmpty;var d,e,c={};try{for(d=0;d<b.length;d++)if(e=b[d],words=_.words(e),words.length)if(words.length>=3&&"CREATE"==words[0].toUpperCase()&&"TABLE"==words[1].toUpperCase()){for(var f=2;!words[f].match(inQuotes)&&f<words.length;)f++;if(f>=words.length)throw"Cannot find table name in CREATE TABLE statement.";var g=_.trim(words[f],"`'\"");c[g]={header:[],values:[]};var h=_(e).chain().strRight("(").strLeftBack(")").words(",").value();if(c[g].header=_.reduce(h,function(a,b){var c=_.words(b);if(!c.length)throw"Cannot find columns for table "+g;var d=_.trim(c[0]);return(_.startsWith(d,"'")||_.startsWith(d,"`")||_.startsWith(d,'"'))&&a.push(_.trim(d,"`'\"")),a},[]),!c[g].header.length)throw"No columns found for table "+g}else if(words.length>=4&&"INSERT"==words[0].toUpperCase()&&"INTO"==words[1].toUpperCase()&&words[2].match(inQuotes)&&"VALUES"==words[3].toUpperCase()){var g=_.trim(words[2],"`'\"");if(!c[g])throw"Table "+g+" was not defined in a CREATE TABLE.";for(var f=(c[g],3);"VALUES"!=words[f].toUpperCase()&&f<words.length;)f++;if(f==words.length||"VALUES"!=words[f].toUpperCase())throw"Error parsing INSERT INTO statement. Cannot find VALUES.";if(f+=1,f==words.length)throw"Error parsing INSERT INTO statement. No values found after VALUES.";var j=_.trim(words.slice(f).join(" ")).replace(/(\))\s*,\s*(\()/g,"),(").replace(/^\(/,"").replace(/\)$/,"").split("),(");_.each(j,function(a){var b=_.words(a,",");c[g].values.push(_.map(b,function(a){return _.trim(a," `'\"")}))})}else if(words.length>=4&&"INSERT"==words[0].toUpperCase()&&"INTO"==words[1].toUpperCase()&&words[2].match(inQuotes)&&_.startsWith(words[3],"(")){var g=_.trim(words[2],"`'\"");if(!c[g])throw"Table "+g+" was not defined in a CREATE TABLE.";for(var f=(c[g],3);"VALUES"!=words[f].toUpperCase()&&f<words.length;)f++;if(f==words.length||"VALUES"!=words[f].toUpperCase())throw"Error parsing INSERT INTO statement. Cannot find VALUES.";var k=_.map(words.slice(3,f),function(a){return _.trim(a,"(), `'\"")});if(!k.length)throw"Error parsing INSERT INTO statement. No column names found for table "+g+" in "+words[3];if(words[3],f+=1,f==words.length)throw"Error parsing INSERT INTO statement. No values found after VALUES.";var j=_.trim(words.slice(f).join(" ")).replace(/(\))\s*,\s*(\()/g,"),(").replace(/^\(/,"").replace(/\)$/,"").split("),(");_.each(j,function(a){var b=_.words(a,",");if(b.length!=k.length)throw"Error parsing INSERT INTO statement. Values "+a+" does not have the same number of items as columns "+words[3];var d={};_.each(c[g].header,function(a){var c=_.indexOf(k,a),e=c!=-1?_.trim(b[c]," `'\""):null;d[a]=e}),c[g].values.push(_.values(d))})}}catch(a){throw"Error: "+a+"\n..."+e}var l={};return _.each(c,function(a,b){var c=a.header;l[b]=_.map(a.values,function(a){for(var b={},d=0;d<c.length;d++)b[c[d]]=a[d];return b})}),l}_.mixin(s.exports());var errorEmpty="Please upload a file or type in something.",inQuotes=new RegExp(/(^`.*`$)|(^'.*'$)|(^".*"$)/);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to export a MySQL database to JSON?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5036605/how-to-export-a-mysql-database-to-json)

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39216133/convert-sql-dump-to-json

Comment: I want to do it in nodejs

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reference that you mentioned, [sql2json](http://www.csvjson.com/sql2json), is opensource. You can use its `convert` function in [sql2json.js](https://github.com/martindrapeau/csvjson-app/blob/cbb0d630cda6125f4ae39ae994efbbe68e4b33ac/js/csvjson/sql2json.js). Here is a basic demo in browser https://jsfiddle.net/j2naprd8/1/

Comment: Thank you you make my day, I just update my question

Answer (score 0):

I think that the most simple way is to import your backup to database, export it in CSV and then convert CSV to JSON.